# Reducibility of the representation $\bigwedge^2(\mathbb{C}^4)$ of $U(4)$.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, exterior-algebra

I am given to understand that $\bigwedge^2(\mathbb{C}^4)$ is not irreducible, as a complex representation of the group $U(4)$ of $4 \times 4$ unitary matrices. My explanation is that $\dim_\mathbb{C} \left( \bigwedge^2(\mathbb{C}^4) \right) = 6$, whereas I seem to have read in section 23 of [these notes](https://math.berkeley.edu/~teleman/math/RepThry.pdf) that the irreducible representations of $U(4)$ are of the form $(\det)^n \otimes \operatorname{Sym}^k(\mathbb{C}^4)$. In particular, the possible dimensions of irreducible representations would be $\binom{4+k-1}{k}$ which takes values $1,4,10,\ldots$.

> **Question:** Supposing I am not labouring under a misapprehension here, do we have a conceptually clear splitting of $\bigwedge^2(\mathbb{C}^4)$ into irreducible representations?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the author's notation $S_d$ which seems to denote something more complicated that $\mathrm{Sym}^d$. For a start, I don't think $\mathrm{Sym}^k(\mathbb C^n)$ can be irreducible (wouldn't the $x \otimes x \otimes \cdots x$ vectors span a submodule?).

Comment: @PseudoNeo: You're write, I got mixed up looking at Proposition 22.9, which is only for $U(2)$. So, do you think this representation might be irreducible?

Comment: This representation is irreducible, and more generally, $\Lambda^k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is an irreducible representation of $U(n)$ for all $k$ and $n$. This follows from Schur-Weyl duality (https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/four-flavors-of-schur-weyl-duality/) although more direct proofs are also possible.